# Prove that if $A,B$ are infinite sets of naturals, and $A\subseteq B$, then $a_A$ is a subsequence of $a_B$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

Let $a:\mathbb{N}\to \mathbb{R}$ be a sequence and $A$ an infinite set of naturals. We use the notation $a_A$ to denote the subsequence of $\underline{a}$ along the set $A$. More precisely, $(a_A):\mathbb{N}\to \mathbb{R}$ is defined by $(a_A)_n = a_{\sigma_A(n)}$ where $\sigma_A$ is the choice function. Prove that if $A,B$ are infinite sets of naturals, and $A\subseteq B$, then $a_A$ is a subsequence of $a_B$.

I'm not sure how to relate the sets to being a sub-sequence?

Any guidance is appreciated !

Comment: With choice function you mean that $\sigma_A$ is the unique monotonous bijection $\Bbb N\to A$?

Comment: Won't you have a $\sigma_B$ choice function as well? Are you assuming it is an extension of $\sigma_A$? To me this only seems true if your choice function preserves the ordering of $\Bbb N$.

Comment: Do you really mean *choice function*? Or is $\sigma_A$ the function that enumerates $A$ in increasing order?